# How can I play a sine/square wave using Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, playback

I'm trying to play a sine wave using Pygame's `sndarray.make_sound` function. However, when I use this array to play it:

`np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(44100) * 440 / 44100).astype(np.float32)`

where `440` is the frequency and `44100` is the sample rate, a loud, jarring noise plays instead. This works using `pyaudio.PyAudio()`, however I need something that doesn't block execution. This happens with square waves, too, however there it just doesn't play anything. I'm using `channels=1` for the `mixer.pre_init` and `mixer.init` functions.

How can I fix this? If it helps, I'm using a Mac. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the numpy array directly to a [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) object and [`play`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play) it. The jarring sound occurs because you're probably sending 32bit float samples to the mixer when it's expecting 16bit integer samples. If you want to use an array of 32bit floats, you must set the `size` parameter of the mixer's init function to 32:

```py
import pygame
import numpy as np

pygame.mixer.init(size=32)

buffer = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(44100) * 440 / 44100).astype(np.float32)
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer)

sound.play(0)
pygame.time.wait(int(sound.get_length() * 1000))
```

Comment: @AlexSpurling As intended